# ImgAreaSelect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, img-area-select-jquery

I am new in jquery. my task in jquery is  "ImgAreaSelect"
I am trying this from morning but not achive the goal. please review my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ladybug_ant').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        onSelectEnd: function(img, selection){
            if (!selection.width || !selection.height){
                return;
            }
            $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
            $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
            $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
            $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
            $('#w').val(selection.width);
            $('#h').val(selection.height); 
        }
    });
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" id="ladybug_ant">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's exactly your question? what's not working. a little input: try adding the javascript/imgareaselect code AFTER the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the plugin itself that you have to download from http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

jQuery is just the Core and does not include an image area select method

After loading the plugin you will be able to use `$('#ladybug_ant').imgAreaSelect({ .. });`

This is an example http://jsfiddle.net/8TwRJ/

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem.I made some changes in Css and Bingo,It is resolved.
Actully the parent div position should be relative to make imagearea scrollable.

You has to define the "parent:"imgParentDivID"" and set position:relative of that div.
It will work perfectly.

**Code:**

```
<div id="imgParentDivID" style="position:relative">
<img id="imgID" src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-   plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" id="ladybug_ant">
</div>

$("#imgID").imgAreaSelect({
        parent: "#imgParentDivID",           
            aspectRatio: '1:1',
            handles: true,
            fadeSpeed: 200,
            selectionOpacity: 1,               
            onSelectChange: preview
        });
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have used script tag for the css link. Use "link" tag instead of "script" tag also i.e use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css"/>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/css/imgareaselect-animated.css"></script>
```

this will solve the issue without any further changes.